# Sort list of rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, rectangles

I want to put a list of words in order of how they appeared on the page they were found. (Including multiple lines if that is the case)

```
the quick brown
fox jumped
```

I have a list of custom `Word` objects that contain the text of the word, and it's left, right, top, and bottom values with (0, 0) being the top left corner of the page.

```
words.Add(new Word() { text = "the", box = new rectangle() { left = 10, right = 30, top = 10, bottom = 21 } );
words.Add(new Word() { text = "brown", box = new rectangle() { left = 65, right = 95, top = 11, bottom = 20 } );
words.Add(new Word() { text = "jumped", box = new rectangle() { left = 36, right = 64, top = 26, bottom = 38 } );
words.Add(new Word() { text = "quick", box = new rectangle() { left = 35, right = 60, top = 11, bottom = 24 } );
words.Add(new Word() { text = "fox", box = new rectangle() { left = 10, right = 30, top = 25, bottom = 35 } );

internal class Word
{
    internal Rectangle box { get; set; }
    internal string text { get; set; }
}
```

I can easily sort a single line by ordering by the left bound, but 2 lines is hurting my brain.

Comment: ps. I know my "Rectangle' is not in the right format with width and height. I simplified it for understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OrderBy` and then `ThenBy` in [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), which will order it by the X position, and then sort it by the Y position.

```
List<Word> sortedWords = words.OrderBy(w => w.box.Left).ThenBy(w => w.box.Top).ToList();
```

Comment: Looks great. I have never used the 'ThenBy' function. I will try it out now.

Comment: It is similar to `OrderBy`, however `OrderBy` re-orders the entire sequence, while `ThenBy` only reorders based on the given property (Ex: It orders by `Y` for all values that have the SAME `X`)